# Is there a faster method to compute the composition of 2 3D rotations than directly using the formula for quaternion product?

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

I have 2 rotations `R_1` and `R_2` in 3D that are described by the unit quaternions `q_1` and `q_2`. I know that the composition `R_2(R_1)` is described by the unit quaternion `q_2 x q_1`. Fair enough, and easy enough to implement.

However, calculating the product of 2 quaternions is a bit expensive (16 multiplications, 12 additions if I am not mistaken). I know that there are smarter ways to compute the rotation of a vector `v` by a unit quaternion `q` than directly applying the `q x [v, 0] x q*` formula (see for example https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/rotating-vector3-by-a-quaternion and the discussion in the fist answer, their "Rodriguez" formula is about 35% less expensive to compute).

My question is: are there similar "smarter ways" to compute the product of 2 unit quaternions / composition of 2 rotations in 3D, in such a way as to need fewer operations?

---

Edit 1: I need truly to be able to compose these rotations, not just to take a "rotation of rotation", as discussed in the comments. This is because, while I "reduce" the problem description to composing 2 rotations, in reality I will be composing the "current rotation" with some "additional new rotation on top of it" many time.

Comment: Do you need the composition itself, or do you only need to rotate vectors by the composition? In the latter case, you can of course write `v' = q_2 x (q_1 x [v, 0] x q_1*) x q_2*`.

Comment: Good point. I need the composition, since here I show only the composition of 2 rotations, but in reality I will have several repetitions of "composing the total rotation with one more rotation on top of it".

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment related to the "faster method" part of the question.

Quaternion multiplication, i.e. Hamilton product between quaternions $\mathbf{q}_2 = r_2 + x_2 \mathbf{i} + y_2 \mathbf{j} + z_2 \mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{q}_1 = r_1 + x_1 \mathbf{i} + y_1 \mathbf{j} + z_1 \mathbf{k}$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{q}_2 \times \mathbf{q}_1 = ~ & ( r_2 r_1 - x_2 x_1 - y_2 y_1 - z_2 z_1 ) \\
~ = ~ & ( r_2 x_1 + x_2 r_1 + y_2 z_1 - z_2 y_1 ) ~ \mathbf{i} \\
~ = ~ & ( r_2 y_1 - x_2 z_1 + y_2 r_1 + z_2 x_1 ) ~ \mathbf{j} \\
~ = ~ & ( r_2 z_1 + x_2 y_1 - y_2 x_1 + z_2 r_1 ) ~ \mathbf{k} \\
\end{aligned}$$
(corresponding to a rotation by $\mathbf{q}_1$ followed by a rotation by $\mathbf{q}_2$), and indeed does consist of $16$ *scalar* multiplications and $12$ additions or subtractions, but it is also one of the operations that *vectorize* extremely well (if suitably written) on hardware architectures with single-instruction multiple data support; especially SSE3 and AVX (on AMD64/x86-64, or 64-bit Intel and AMD processors).

For example, using SSE, a single 128-bit register can describe a full quaternion in IEEE 754-2008 binary32 aka [single-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format; using AVX, a single 128-bit register can describe a full quaternion in IEEE 754 binary64 aka [double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format.  Then, the core cost of the Hamilton product is just four vector multiplications and three additions, if one of the multiplicands can be shuffled (negating two components) into four different forms.

Furthermore, since all the quaternion components are within $-1$ and $+1$, a range of $-4$ to $+4$ suffices for the quaternion representation, and one can use [Qm.n fixed-point integer representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) for the quaternions; real component $f$ is then approximated by integer value $i = \lfloor f \cdot 2^n \rceil$ (where $\lfloor \rceil$ represents rounding to nearest integer), $-2^{m-1} \le i \lt 2^{m+1}$, so that even slow 8-bit microcontrollers can use unit quaternions efficiently (for example for orientation tracking using cheap [IMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) modules like MPU9150).  In some robotics etc. implementations on 32-bit ARM architectures without hardware floating-point support, this can yield very significant speedups (and using Q3.28 format, yields up to four additional bits of precision per component, compared to single-precision floating-point).

Therefore, depending on the *hardware* (and of course programming language and libraries) used, you probably want to use an optimized unit quaternion (versor) library for the best real-world performance, as many current processors have features that make the theoretically more costly form much more efficient (up to 4× faster on SSE/AVX) than it looks.

I do have written a Python module (in Python) extending tuple to represent versors in plain Python, complementing 3D vector and matrix types (and their respective operations), but my use cases have only involved a few thousand quaternion operations per second at most; so optimizing that code would have had basically zero impact on the efficiency of the Python code.

So, if these unit quaternion operations truly are a bottleneck for your use case – do check, do not just *assume* it is! –, you might wish to consider asking this question on the programming sub-forum here instead.  Personally, for Python, I'd probably implement a basic versor library in C, with both a vectorized `<immintrin.h>` and a "naïve" non-vectorized implementation, and both C and Python test suites to verify, that exposes a four-component tuple-like Python data type describing an unit quaternion (and uses the vector components of the same to describe ordinary 3D vectors, for optimal vectorization in exchange for a bit more memory used per vector).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is. You can multiply two general quaternions using only 8 scalar multiplications (instead of the naïve 16) at the cost of some extra additions and bitshifts. This is achieved with a bilinear method akin to Gauss' complex multiplication using 3 products or Strassen's  2x2 matrix multiplication with 7 products, and can be done as follows.

Given the quaternions:

$$
q_1 = r_1 + x_1 i + y_1 j + z_1 k \\
q_2 = r_2 + x_2 i + y_2 j + z_2 k
$$

we can define the following 8 products:

$$
m_1 = +2 r_1 r_2 \\
m_2 = -2 z_1 y_2 \\
m_3 = -2 x_1 z_2 \\
m_4 = -2 y_1 x_2 \\
m_5 = \frac{1}{4} (r_1+x_1+y_1+z_1) (r_2+x_2+y_2+z_2) \\
m_6 = \frac{1}{4} (r_1-x_1+y_1-z_1) (r_2-x_2+y_2-z_2) \\
m_7 = \frac{1}{4} (r_1+x_1-y_1-z_1) (r_2+x_2-y_2-z_2) \\
m_8 = \frac{1}{4} (r_1-x_1-y_1+z_1) (r_2-x_2-y_2+z_2)
$$

which can be linearly combined into the product quaternion:

$$
q = q_1 \times q_2 = r + x i + y j + z k
$$

with

$$
r = m_1 - m_5 - m_6 - m_7 - m_8 \\
x = m_2 + m_5 - m_6 + m_7 - m_8 \\
y = m_3 + m_5 + m_6 - m_7 - m_8 \\
z = m_4 + m_5 - m_6 - m_7 + m_8
$$

Multiplication by $\pm 2$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ have trivial cost on a digital computer. The $24+16=40$ additions can be rearranged into no more than 24, effectively substituting 8 multiplications with 12 additions/subtractions.

As usual, one should always consider the potential loss of numerical precision and other implementation practicalities when choosing a more complex algorithm over the simpler one.

Comment: +1 Huge help, thanks! Only note, I think that final line should be $z=m_4+m_5-m_6\mathbf{-m_7+m_8}$. Either that or my simple test script has failed me, which would be painfully characteristic.

Comment: @Tom Yes, you are correct! Thank you for noticing.